# Placing two buttons on both edges of AppBar, mui

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

How to place 2 buttons on left edge, giving at least 10px space from left edge and another button on right edge of AppBar of mui in react?

Can we do this without use of grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this line of code to fill the space between two buttons

```
     <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[MUI Toolbar](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/toolbar/) is made for this purpose. The docs say *The Toolbar is a flex container, allowing flex item properties to be used to lay out the children.* So, **flex** is used, not grid. The [Basic App Bar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#basic-app-bar) example in the docs demonstrates how you can layout buttons within Toolbar inside the App Bar: Two buttons are on the left, and one button is on the right.